# GitHub Pages 上で CSS が反映されない

Tags: html, css, github-pages

GitHub Pages を用いて作成したHPをアップロードしようとしましたが、CSSだけがうまく反映されませんでした。
対処の仕方を教えてください。お願いします。

以下、コード

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>飯南高等学校 地域応援隊HP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/portfolio-demo/style.css">
</head>
```

以下、試したこと

- PCの再起動
- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` を `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/portfolio-demo/style.css">` と変更

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あなたのGitHubアカウントで portfolio-demo というリポジトリが見当たりません。
正しくは nayutas-room ではありませんか？

https://github.com/nayuta-ichino/nayutas-room
https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/nayutas-room

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/nayutas-room/style.css"> というふうに変更すれば良い、ということでしょうか。

Comment: ファイル名も間違っているように見えます。正しくは  stylesheet.css じゃないでしょうか？

Comment: うまく反映されました。ありがとうございました